# Gnu Parallel: Does parallel reload program for every job?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

Suppose I have a program that loads significant content before running...but this is a one time slowdown.

Next, I write:

```
cat ... | parallel -j 8 --spreadstdin --block $sz ... ./mycode
```

Will this induce the load overhead every single job?

If it does induce the overhead, is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: It just runs the program multiple times, it doesn't change how the program itself operates.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark hmm, I was thinking named pipes or something.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark gnu parallel is pretty impressive, once you get tired of mallocing and copying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Barmar says, `./mycode` is started for each block in your example.

But since you do not use `-k` in your example you may be able to use `--round-robin`.

```
... | parallel -j 8 --spreadstdin --round-robin --block $sz ... ./mycode
```

This will start 8 `./mycode`s (but not one per block) and give blocks to any process that is ready to read.

This example shows that more blocks are given to process 11 and 10 than process 4 and 5 because 4 and 5 read slower:

```
seq 1000000 |
  parallel -j8 --tag --roundrobin --pipe --block 1k 'pv -qL {}0000 | wc' ::: 11 4 5 6 9 8 7 10
```

Answer (score 1):

`parallel` doesn't know anything about the internal workings of the program you're running with it. Each instance runs independently, there's no way that one invocation's initialization can be copied over to the others.

If you want the application to initialize once and then run multiple instances in parallel, you need to design that into the application itself. It should load the data, then use `fork()` to create multiple processes that use this data.